# Glass showing black opaque elliptical reflection

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, glass, reflection

I have a problem with glass, which emits a strange black opaque elliptical reflection that can be seen in the picture, instead of being transparent as it should be. Number 4 in the first picture shows an elliptical reflection that also appears on a non-glass surface.

I posted pictures where you can see the node scheme and render. For the light I use Easy HDRI and point light with a light intensity of 800W, the render engine is cycles and a blender 2.93.

My file is [here](https://mega.nz/file/FZQWBT7a#PBL2IjjtN-E6ldWMQP-dtpDpzgUeK_K39dMGbTC4m-w)

[image]

[image]
[image]

---

I apologize to the administrators as I don't know how to put a link to the blend file. I hope it's this good.

[Blend file link](https://mega.nz/file/FZQWBT7a#PBL2IjjtN-E6ldWMQP-dtpDpzgUeK_K39dMGbTC4m-w).

Answer (score 2):

Try to check normals of glass objects. And if you have smooth shading on them, try to switch to flat shading or add an Edge Split modifier.

If you can share blend file, I may look into it.

EDIT> Found it. In "Object data" tab, Normals" card you need to switch off "Auto smooth" option for all glass objects.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to share blend file. I posted a link with a blend file that I uploaded to the mega cloud, but the administrator deleted the link.    Maybe this is good [Blend file link](https://mega.nz/file/FZQWBT7a#PBL2IjjtN-E6ldWMQP-dtpDpzgUeK_K39dMGbTC4m-w).

Comment: I have found it, and updated the answer. Try that, please.

Comment: And, more, in file that you shared you have switched inputs to Mix Shader node. It should be as you posted here, output from glass shader first and transperent one second.

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot for help. Now I can finish my work.